# Language Injection Rule PhpStorm -> JavaScript in Twig Block

Tags: javascript, twig, phpstorm, craftcms

I'm working with CraftCMS, which uses Twig. One of the methods I use to add JS is e.g.

```
{% js at endBody %}
    console.log('I am JavaScript');
{% endjs %}
```

I want to have it permanently highlighted as JavaScript, and not have to reinject it every time I open PhpStorm again.

According to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-language-injections.html#configure-injection-rules I need to add an injection rule. So I went to

1. Editor
2. Language Injections
3. Add (+)
4. Generic Twig
5. (See image)

[image: Language Injection Settings in PhpStorm]

What do I have to enter in this window though? I'm a bit lost here. Any help is valuable :)

Comment: Did you try clicking the (?) in the corner? Jetbrains's help is pretty useful... https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/language-injection-settings-generic-javascript.html

Comment: @AKX no I didn't, but even after checking out the page, it wouldn't really have helped me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just add a pattern for matching your custom `js` Twig tag:

```
+ twigCustomStatement("js")
```

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/language-injection-settings-generic-twig.html

**P.S.** PhpStorm already has a bundled similar rule for `script` Twig tag. It does exactly the same. The only difference is in the tag name: `script` versus your `js`.

[image]

---

The final result (notice the light green background that indicates the Language Injection rule in action + syntax colors for JS code; shows both your tag and bundled one):

[image]
*(NOTE: copy+pasting in the file, re-opening the file or the whole project/IDE may be needed to have new Injection rule to be applied)*

Proof that it's a JavaScript:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. So thorough I have nothing else to say hahaha. I could have guessed that there are existing rules, but I didn't see them. I just had to reopen the files for it to apply. Closing and opening the project didn't help. Thanks